# Selenium WebDriver: Get value of DIV without a class name but with category name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, find

I am trying to use selenimum webdriver in python 3.

My html source is for example:

```
<div the-category="Cat1"...></div>
<div the-category="Cat2"...></div>
```

I know that if instead of `category`, I had class for example:

```
<div class="Cat1"...></div>
<div class="Cat2"...></div>
```

I could find the first `div` by:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('Cat1')
```

but how can I find the first `div` in the:

```
<div the-category="Cat1"...></div>
<div the-category="Cat2"...></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[the-category="Cat1"]')
```